# How do I use *ngIf to show one line of text based on *ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have to write a simple task manager app using Ionic. For the completed task section, there needs to be a text line "Completed tasks" that only shows if any of the tasks are marked as completed. We've been told to write it using the *ngIf directive but I cannot figure it out.

I've tried using the item in ngFor to get the boolean value of the task but I know it's wrong because it prints the line every time I mark one as completed. This is the code I have for the completed task section, it uses a Pipe to filter the completed ones from the list. The "Completed tasks" line has to print only if there's a task with the completed value in true.

Is there a way to check if any of the values in the array is true so that it prints the line and hides it if all the tasks are incomplet?
Thank you in advance!

```
<h1>Completed tasks</h1>
<ion-list no-lines>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of tareaServicio.lista|pipeFinalizado2">
       <ion-label color="medium" [ngStyle]="estiloLinea(item)">{{item.descripcion}}</ion-label>
       <ion-checkbox color="medium" checked="true" (ionChange)="finalizarItem(item)"></ion-checkbox>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list. You do not need ngIf.

in .ts file:

```
const filteredList = tareaServicio.lista.filter(item => item.id !== -1); // condition here
```

and then

```
<ion-list no-lines>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of filteredList">
       <ion-label color="medium"><del>{{item.descripcion}}</del></ion-label>
       <ion-checkbox color="medium" checked="true" (ionChange)="finalizarItem(item)"></ion-checkbox>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how complex your logic is when deciding whether a task is completed or not.

If the condition is a simple one, you can do this:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of tareaServicio.lista">
       <ion-label color="medium" [ngStyle]="estiloLinea(item)">{{item.descripcion}}</ion-label>
       <ion-checkbox 
         color="medium" 
         [checked]="item.isCompleted" <!-- You can apply the same logic to other properties as well -->
        (ionChange)="finalizarItem(item)"
       ></ion-checkbox>

</ion-item>
```

However, if your logic is a little bit more complex, you can create a map that will keep track of the status for each item.

```
completedTasksMap: { [k: string]: boolean } = {};

ngOnInit() {
 this.apiService.get(...)
  .subscribe(this.handleReceivedTasks.bind(this))
}

handleReceivedTasks (tasks) {
 this.taskList = tasks;

 tasks.forEach(t => (this.completedTasksMap[t.id] = this.isTaskCompleted(t) ))
}

private isTaskCompleted (t): boolean { /* ... */ }
```

And your template would look like this:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of taskList">
       <ion-label color="medium" [ngStyle]="estiloLinea(item)">{{item.descripcion}}</ion-label>
       <ion-checkbox 
         color="medium" 
         [checked]="completedTasksMap[item.id]"
        (ionChange)="finalizarItem(item)"
       ></ion-checkbox>

</ion-item>
```